# Why does querySelector come up as null even though the class name it is looking for appears 21 times in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, grid, getboundingclientrect

I'm trying to find the height of an item that I have here. The item is formatted as such:

```
<div class="press-item">
<span class="press-title">MUSIC IS MY RADAR</span>
<span class="press-title">“Like It Never Happened” Review</span>
<img src="http:...jpg">
<span class="press-subtitle">1st May 2020...Empire.</span>
<a href="https://themusic...-review/">Read More</a></div>
```

Several of these are in one large container div, class `press-blocks`. My CSS looks like this:

```
.press-blocks{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2em;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-auto-rows: 0;
}
.press-item{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

In Javascript, I'm trying to find the height of each individual `press-item` div. I have this:

```
function buildpress(Object){
                var allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("press-item");

                for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++){
                    resizeItem(allItems[i]);
                }
            }
            function resizeItem(item){
                var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("press-blocks")[0],
                    rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue("grid-row-gap")),
                    rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));

                var rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector(".press-item").getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap)/(rowHeight+rowGap));

                item.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + rowSpan;
            }
            buildpress()
```

When I run the page, it tells me ``Cannot read property ' getBoundingClientRect' of null'. It shouldn't be null, my html has 21 of divs with that classname.
I'm trying to do something similar to the tutorial at https://w3bits.com/css-grid-masonry/.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you meant to call `item.querySelector(".press-title")`  because `item` is the one with class name `.press-item`.